# GattDeviceService close/dispose missing or unimplemented?

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal

EDIT: I am using the Win 10 SDK version 10.0.17134.0 and Visual Studio 2017 with on up to date Windows 10

Hello,
I've been writing code to use the windows 10 (UWP) Bluetooth Low Energy API.
I've noticed that after some large number of runs of my application, my bluetooth stops working for my entire system (requiring a reboot). This has been happening typically once per day. My current assumption is that I am not properly cleaning up whatever allocations are caused by my application and I am hitting some internal limit in the windows Bluetooth LE subsystem.

Looking into the API, I notice that most of the BLE objects do not even expose a cleanup function. However, according to the documentation for [GattDeviceService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice) it should expose a Close() and Dispose() method...

intellisense agrees with this, showing autocomplete for both the Close() and Dispose() methods.

However, calling either and compiling results in an error like

> Error C2039 'Close': is not a member of
>   'Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattDeviceService'

I've spent quite a bit of time looking at example code and google results for the Windows 10 BLE API... At this point I am just assuming it's incomplete?

Does anyone know how to properly cleanup from Windows 10 BLE API calls or whether it's even possible?

Sorry for the relatively open-ended question, at this point I'm not really even 100% sure what I'm looking for...

Edit: here is some code which reproduces my issue:

```
auto leDevice = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(addr);
Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattDeviceServicesResult^ gatt = co_await leDevice->GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < gatt->Services->Size; i++){
    GenericAttributeProfile::GattDeviceService^ service = gatt->Services->GetAt(i);
    auto result = co_await service->OpenAsync(GenericAttributeProfile::GattSharingMode::SharedReadOnly)
    //... do stuff with service / characteristics
    service->Close()
}
```

My code actually works without the OpenAsync line, IDK if it's needed

Comment: Could you provide the code that how you call the Close method in your c++ project? You said you used the 17134 SDK, do you mean your app target and min version 17134? And your device OS build is 17134?

Comment: yes give me a little while to make a minimized reproduce.

in my project properties I see:

    Target platform: windows 10 

    Windows SDK Version: 10.0.17134.0


I am a linux developer normally so I don't know if there are other places where this would be set

Comment: Edited original post, thanks

Comment: I can see the error from Close method and we are looking into it. For your original issue, I would recommend you to diagnose your project using Visual Studio to see whether there are some objects have memory leaks. You can use the tool in Debug=>profiler=>performance profiler… then select the Memory usage, after that you can start the diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `service->Close()` and `service->Dispose()` don't work even though they appear in the documentation. However, doing `delete service` seems to work fine for me and appears to have the same result.